# How to call collectstatic management command programatically using call_command with options like -l or --noinput

Tags: python, django

I am trying to call collectstatic command usig call_command but when I want to use option like -l or --noinput

```
django.core.management.call_command('collectstatic','--noinput')
```

Its giving me an error

```
CommandError: Command doesn't accept any arguments
```

Please let me know how can I call this, how to pass this options.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 9):

This is covered in Django's official Documentation: (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code) the proper way to call the command should be:

```
from django.core.management import call_command

call_command('collectstatic', verbosity=0, interactive=False)
```

Comment: but how can we give other options like '-l' , '-i', '-n','-c', when I tried its giving me above mentioned error in my question

Comment: but I want remaining options also @petkostas

Comment: If you take the time and actually read the Documentation you will understand how you pass extra arguments...hint `call_command('collectstatic', verbosity=0, interactive=False, link=True, clear=True)` add accordingly what else is needed...

Answer (score 1):

Check the source code of [collectstatic.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py)

Inside `add_arguments` function, the `dest` keyword is what you are looking for. You then pass that value to `call_command()` as argument.

EDIT: However, looking more carefully, I see that, `-l`, `-c`, `-n` have no `dest`. Thus it's unclear know how to pass those arguments :(